# GORM/grails deep distinct association query criteria

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have domain objects for each table specified in the below query. I'm having trouble creating the withCriteria closure representing the below SQL query. Any thoughts?
Thanks!
Steve

SQL Query:

```
select A_NAME from A 
where A_XID = 
  (select A_XID from B
   where B_XID = 
     (select distinct B_XID from C
      where D_XID = '${d.dXid}')
```

Domain Objects:

```
class A {
  String aName
  BigDecimal aXid         <-- unique identifier
}

class B {
    A a
    BigDecimal bXid   <-- unique identifier
}

class C {
    D d
    B b
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with a criteria query, but in HQL it'd be

```
String aName = A.executeQuery(
   'select c.b.a.aName from C c where c.d = :d',
   [d: d])[0]
```

but you've left out a lot of information, so this is based on the assumption that you have these domain classes (you omitted the D class and mappings):

```
class A {
   String aName
   BigDecimal aXid
}

class B {
   A a
   BigDecimal bXid
   static mapping = {
      a column: 'A_XID'
   }
}

class C {
   D d
   B b
   static mapping = {
      b column: 'B_XID'
      d column: 'D_XID'
   }
}

class D {
   String someProperty
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Burt! In principle, the suggested solution works. But it misses the explicit "distinct" portion of the query. Grabbing the first element gives a distinct value, but a large amount of data is still pulled over the network from the database. That's the key point I was hoping get answered. How to only pull one value over the network.

Comment: Adding "distinct" to the provided query gave the expected results. Setting the logSql property in DataSource.groovy showed the correct SQL created with "distinct". Thanks again for your help! It's definitely a lot cleaner then using the SQL.